# iPhone - Custom TableViewCell height calculated off cell text

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm creating a custom cell in the cellForRowAtIndex function and filling it with my dynamic text. The height of the cell is variable based upon this text so I need to user the heightForRowAt function, but in that function I don't have the cell. I can create a new one and fill it with the text and then call my calculateHeight function on it but then I'm creating 2 cells for each row.

Anyone have a better method? Cache the cells yourself in the cellForRow function in a dictionary by row index and use that? Is cellForRow called before heightForRow?

I've managed to crash Xcode4 twice so far playing around with this so am hoping someone has done this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

is called before

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Creating two cells is a possible solution, but creating two cells isn't a very effective method. However, you don't need the cell to calculate the height; All you need is the string.

You'll probably want to use

```
sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:
```

on your string to calculate the height.

I could provide details on how to do that, but you should be able to figure it out from reading the documentation.

Comment: This is what I did, but then the Cell height calculating function is in my view controlller. Not a huge deal, but now I have to paste more code to include my custom cell

Comment: @Mark Then you're doing the right thing in the wrong place. It should be a class method of the custom cell, not an instance method of your controller.

Comment: Since I cannot call cellForRowAt.. in the heightForRowAt.. function currently due to a crash bug, I duplicate creating the cell in the height function than call cell.calculateHeight which calculates its own height based on the strings and how they are laid out.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is you make a class method on your custom cell (for instance), which knows the values of how things (statically sized things) will be set, and does some math to determine given the offsets of the text view for instance, it can tell you how big the cell needs to be after calculating how high your string will be given a font.